# Is it possible to run a JavaScript (NodeJS) command/function and let the program continue if there's an error?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, error-handling

I was wondering whether there's a way to run a function in JavaScript and let the program ignore it if there's an error running the function?

```
player.play('./sounds/throughQueue.mp3', function(err){
                                   if (err) throw err
                                   })
```

Pretty much like this without the "throw err".

The program should just continue.

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: uhm... yes? why not?

Comment: Not totally sure what you're asking, but wouldn't `try { someFunction() } catch (err) { /* do nothing */ }` do the trick?

Comment: a try catch wouldn't catch an asynchronously thrown error.

Comment: Just don't throw the error.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: @KevinB But, wouldn't you be able to handle an async error in the `error` or `fail` callback conditions that most async operations support?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, but that wouldn't involve wrapping the outer function in a try catch. That would only make sense within an async/await fn.

Comment: @KevinB Yes. That's what I thought.

Comment: A program can of course ignore whether there was an error, but it can usually not ignore that there is no result. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments you want to know how to handle async function error; 
You could do something like this:

```
function myAsyncFunction(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do some async anction that returns error
    foo.asyncCall((err, item) => err && reject(err))
  }
}

myAsyncFunction().catch(e => console.error(e))
```

If you observe code above async error was handled in two styles:

1. Callback function usually has 1st arg returning error and you can do `if (err)` and add any logic you want in there. Or just ignore it.
2. Within `Promise` you can use `reject` which is second argument in constructor. And when you reject error, you can use `.catch` method upon that `Promise` and use any custom logic you want, either new promise call or function callback.

Note I used `console.error` within callback function, you could just do nothing there and it will be ignored (your program will continue)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can ignore callback/promise error or swallow try/catch caught error, but it can only make the execution go on, not make the behavior or result correctness.

1. If in the callback function, you can ignore error with empty error handling and the execution won't break either, **but the behavior is still dependent on if there is error in the invocation**.
2. If in promise then, you can also ignore errors caught.
3. If in async/await way, you must try/catch the invocation and swallow the caught err.

In a word, I suggest you handle the possible errors. after all, quality software is what we want. and what maybe happen will happen eventually.